# Is there an alternative/similar command to Spyder's runfile() or a workaround?

Tags: java, python, spyder

I want to run a python script outside of spyder, but all the time till now I was using **runfile**() to run my scripts. I was using the **wdir**="my/working/dir" to pass the working directory to the script but now that I want to run the script from console I don't know what to do.

So is there a way to achieve the same functionality?

actually, I want to run it from a Java program... I do some stuff in Java and I want to run the python scrip to plot some figures.

```
/root
  /dir1/
  /dir2/
  /src
    /javaclass
      /Class.java
    /python
      /script.py
```

I want the script.py to "see" the root directory, without having to go to parent dirs. runfile() has the wdir parameter to do this. Java has the -classpath option. I want something similar.

Comment: It depends on the IDE you want to use the file in

Comment: actually, I want to run it from a Java program... I do some stuff in Java and I want to run the python scrip to plot some figures.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to run a python program from a java program? If so, I would add that information to your question so people can have more details when trying to help you!

Comment: ok, I edited it. I had written that I wanted to run it from console/terminal, that's why I thought I didn't have to be more precise.

Comment: I wrote an answer, check if it works. If it doesn't, I can check what went wrong and update it if needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` from the Java Runtime Class. Here is an example:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python yourapp.py");
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm) on how to use it. This [link](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016/) explains how to read the output.

Comment: I don't think that will work.. my dir structure is this:
 
`/root
      /dir1/
      /dir2/
      /src
           /javaclass
               /Class.java
      /python
           /script.py`

if execute the script as you say, won't the scope of the script be only the /python dir?
I want the script to "see" the root directory, without having to go to parent dirs.
runfile() has the wdir parameter to do this

Comment: edited my question to display properly the directories

Comment: I see. You might have to specify the whole path, unfortunately. However, I am no expert in Java, so there might be other solutions.

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: Windows with Intellij, but since I will be calling `python` to execute the script, does it make any difference?

Comment: I was checking the OS, to see how the path would be formatted